# How to make a Contact Us View in Swift without using MessageUI

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UITextField and a UITextView in a UIView. I would like to have a user enter his/her issue and send it off to an email and then have the view dismiss. Would I make an request using NSURLSession to my email along with that information?

Is this the proper way to go about it?

Comment: There is no built-in way to programmatically send an email the iOS SDK without user interaction.  You either use `MFMailComposeViewController`, or integrate with some service platform to send an email for you.

Comment: So sending an email using nsurl session isn't an option? I'm assuming that an email won't be recognized as a URL?

Comment: `NSURLSession` is for making a web request, not sending an email.

Comment: Hmm, I'm aware of this, but it would seem like a reasonable solution. I would implore you to check out an app like yik yak, which has a contact us view without utilizing `MFMailComposeViewController`

Comment: Like I said, they may integrate with a third-party service such as Mailchip to send an email without `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: I suppose, I will look into it further. Although I'm sure you're right. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Okay, I'm almost certain that they use `MFMessageComposeViewController`, because you can set up your own UI without having to be redirected to the mail app.

Comment: `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn't redirect the user to the mail app, it's a view controller that is presented modally which allows you to send mail using the mail account set up on the device already.  I'm still not sure what you're asking.  If it's "how do I send an email from an app without using the mail view?" then the answer is "you can't" without using a third-party service to send an email from a REST API, like with Mailgun.

Comment: Well that should do it thanks!